# colorbox ie8 windows xp loading issue

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, colorbox

```
<div class="topDivContent">
    <div class="content">
        Sample content Sample content Sample content Sample content
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var displaydiv = '.' + "topDivContent";

        $.colorbox({
            inline : true,
            href : displaydiv,
            innerHeight : 150,
            innerWidth : 650,
            scrolling : false
        });

    });
</script>
```

I have a typical issue of loading the contents using colorbox plugin, on page load I am trying to load contents as show in above.

It is working fine in all environments where as in Windows XP + IE8, it is keep on showing loading symbol. can you please help me out what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar formatting issue for IE-8 only and for me what worked was to use proper `HTML doctype`.

Use `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` and see if it fixed.

Comment: Right now I have html doctype as follow <!DOCTYPE html>, same code is working on IE8 + Windows 7.

Comment: if you look at their website FAQ, it says above DOCTYPE is a requirement for it to work properly for IE8.